# Windows 8: How do I disable search charm

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to disable the search charm once a user navigates to a different page.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;

    _searchPane.QuerySubmitted -= _querySubmittedHandler;
    _searchPane.SuggestionsRequested -= _suggestionsRequestedHandler;
    _searchPane.ResultSuggestionChosen -= OnSearchPaneResultSuggestionChosen;

    _searchPane = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

_searchPane.ShowOnKeyboardInput = false;